# New module service is dependency on old module service - The service has a dependency on a non-existent service

Tags: 8, dependency-injection, symfony-services

I have a new module moduleB. It defines a service that is used in the dependency injection of moduleA.

moduleA is already enabled, its changes are just to the services definition. The info.yml has moduleB as a dependency.

Both moduleA and moduleB are in the core.extension config to be enabled.

moduleB cannot be enabled using config (cim or csim) because the missing dependency from moduleA throws an exception.

How can I get config to enable the missing module before checking the service dependency? Or, how can I restructure to allow the existing module to use the new module service to allow enabling the module through drush ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add moduleA to `core.extension.yml` on a new line (with the other modules) as `module_a: 0`.

Comment: Thanks, thats already done.

Comment: Try just enabling the module first manually: `drush en module_b; drush cim`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that defeats the purpose of the config system. I want to manage this through config so we can utilise CI. Its also worth noting that this also throws the same error. The only way to fix at the moment is to comment out the arguments in services yml

Comment: I might be wrong, but I vaguely remember reading this is a security measure, requiring modules to be manually enabled, as allowing them to be automatically enabled could allow for the insertion of malicious modules.

Comment: Module management in config is very basic functionality of the config system. It is core to our workflow and works perfectly. The problem is not with enabling modules, its with how to get dependencies managed correctly when dependent on services. I definitely would not manage a production site without the modules managed in config - manual enabling is error prone.

Comment: Sure. I don't write the rules. Just work with them. For myself, due to this being an irregular case where an upgrade of a module requires a dependency on a previously non-existing module, thereby requiring manual enabling of a module, I'd schedule it as part of a version upgrade, not a standard CI workflow. I wish you luck on finding a solution that fits your own needs better.

Comment: The module needs to be enabled in `hook_update_N()` function @Christian. This is why the recommended deployment workflow is `drush updb; drush cr; drush cim`, so that update hooks can resolve these potential inconsistencies in config

Comment: Thanks @Clive. So we will then have the module enabled in both core.extension config and `hook_update_N()` as well as a dependency in the info.yml?

Comment: Yes exactly, that covers you from all angles @Christian. `updb` installs the module, `cim` syncs the config (a noop for core.extension in this case as the module is already installed), and if you ever install the module on another site the .info.yml dependency will cover it

Comment: Thanks @Clive that sounds good. Can you add as an answer and I'll select it ?